# Create the database button is not active in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I don't know how to describe the problems with the Oracle SQL developer program. I am new at this. The story is here;

I downloaded Oracle SQL Developer 22.2. And I started sqldeveloper.exe. Oracle SQL Developer is started but I am not doing anything in this program. Everything freezes. The Create database button is inactive. Press the... button and press .. but nothing changes.

My computer is a gaming computer and not old. The hardware is above the minimum requirements to install the program.

I tried resetting the windows factory settings...
I tried deleting and installing it.
I tried the old version of sqldevelepor.exe...

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can check [this](http://abdullahcetinkaya.blogspot.com/2018/07/oracle-sql-developer-ekran-donma-ve.html) out as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tools --> preferences --> environment --> look and feel: windows (not oracle)

Comment: I can't say how much i want to thank YOU! I was going crazy for days that GUI did not load at all but this fixed it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer is a GUI tool we use to access (most usually) an Oracle database.

But, to do that, you **need a database**. According to what you said so far, there's none so - SQL Developer itself can't do much.

I'd suggest you to visit the same site (Oracle Technology Network, OTN) from which you downloaded SQL Developer, and this time download the database. Pick the **Express Edition** (XE) as it is easy to install and use. Along with the installation process, the setup will create the database for you (so you won't have to create it manually).

Then, once it is done, you should be able to use SQL Developer to connect to it. At first, you'll use SYSTEM or SYS users (pay attention to connect as SYSDBA in that case). Don't use these users for anything but administration purposes - create a new user (you can call it e.g. "berfin"), grant privileges to it (most usual are create session, create table, create view, create procedure) so that you could start working with it. In that schema (i.e. user) create your own tables, insert data, do whatever you planned to do).

I believe you should read some documentation first; OTN has it all. Start with the Concepts book, see short DBA (so that you'd be able to create your own user, etc.), have a look at SQL reference book (if you don't know SQL already). That should get you started. On the other hand, you could take *shortcuts* and check some YouTube videos/tutorials, ask here and there, Google for problems you meet but - in a long turn, if you really want to work with Oracle - read documentation.

Comment: I currently have Oracle 19c Express Edition. In order to connect via SYS or SYSTEM, I must be able to press the green plus button that appears at the top left in SQL Developer. But I can't do anything in the GUI, I don't think it has anything to do with authorization because the GUI completely freezes and becomes unusable.

Comment: It seems the program is resource starved...are you running it in a container or native on your machine?

Comment: native, i guess